# iOS connection to Lex Runtime error Code=4 "null"

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

My iOS app could connect to Lex Runtime with no issues - but now it can't and gets this error:

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSLexErrorDomain Code=4 "null" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=null, NSLocalizedFailureReason=DependencyFailedException:http://internal.amazon.com/coral/
```

I have an Cognito federated ID, which has the Lex policies attached. I'm assuming it's a permissions based issue but unsure what has changed to cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it - the error was not with permissions but with the underlying Lambda function which is connected to the Lex bot. The Lambda instance had a coding error which caused the issue; looking through the Lambda Cloudwatch logs showed the error.